# Pandas scalar UDF failing, IllegalArgumentException

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

First off, I apologize if my issue is simple. I did spend a lot of time researching it.

I am trying to set up a scalar Pandas UDF in a PySpark script as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf).

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc.install_pypi_package("pandas")
import pandas as pd
sc.install_pypi_package("PyArrow")

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("a", 1, 0), ("a", -1, 42), ("b", 3, -1), ("b", 10, -2)],
    ("key", "value1", "value2")
)

df.show()

@F.pandas_udf("double", F.PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def pandas_plus_one(v):
    return pd.Series(v + 1)

df.select(pandas_plus_one(df.value1)).show()
# Also fails
#df.select(pandas_plus_one(df["value1"])).show()
#df.select(pandas_plus_one("value1")).show()
#df.select(pandas_plus_one(F.col("value1"))).show()
```

The script fails at the last statement:

> An error occurred while calling o209.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 2 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3
>   in stage 8.0 (TID 30, ip-10-160-2-53.ec2.internal, executor 3):
>   **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**    at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.readMessage(MessageSerializer.java:543)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNext(MessageChannelReader.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.readSchema(ArrowStreamReader.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.initialize(ArrowReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.ensureInitialized(ArrowReader.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(ArrowReader.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
>   ...

What am I missing here? I am just following the manual. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pyarrow rolled out a new version 0.15 on october 5,2019 which causes pandas Udf to throw error.
Spark needs to upgrade to be compatible with this(which might take some time).
You can follow the progress here https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-29367?filter=allissues

**Solution:**

1. **You need to install Pyarrow 0.14.1 or lower.** < sc.install_pypi_package("pyarrow==0.14.1") >
   (or)
2. Set the environment variable **ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1** from where you are using Python

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue has been re-solved.

Comment: Has this been fixed in newer versions of pyarrow, like 0.15.1?

Comment: God bless you! Spent so much time scratching my head around the issue. Installing version 0.14.0 solved it.

Comment: Has this been fixed in newer versions of pyarrow, like 0.15.1? - Not  fixed till 0.16.0

Comment: @SonalDubey The issue is not with pyarrow's new release, it is spark which has to upgrade and become compatible with pyarrow.(i am afraid we have to wait for spark 3.0 to use the latest pyarrow)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the real cause. Will wait for Spark 3.0