# Forecasting with facebook prophet using Pandas udf in spark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, facebook-prophet

I am trying to use Facebook prophet in spark in an Zeppelin environment and I have tried to follow the exact steps from https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/517, However, i get errors like below. I am simply not sure what am I to correct here or how to debug this.

My data contains a datetime features called `ds`, volume that I want to predict `y` and the `segment` and I am trying to build a model for each segment.

`File"/hadoop14/yarn/nm/usercache/khasbab/appcache/application_1588090646020_2412/container_e168_1588090646020_2412_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3737.showString.`

```
%livycd.pyspark

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType,TimestampType,ArrayType,DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from fbprophet import Prophet
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


result_schema = StructType([

    StructField('segment', StringType(), True),
    StructField('ds', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('trend', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('trend_upper', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('trend_lower', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('yearly', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('yearly_upper', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('yearly_lower', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('yhat', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('yhat_upper', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('yhat_lower', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('multiplicative_terms', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('multiplicative_terms_upper', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('multiplicative_terms_lower', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('additive_terms', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('additive_terms_upper', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
    StructField('additive_terms_lower', ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),

    ])

@pandas_udf(result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def forecast_loans(history_pd):

    # instantiate the model, configure the parameters
    model = Prophet(
        interval_width=0.95,
        growth='linear',
        daily_seasonality=False,
        weekly_seasonality=False,
        yearly_seasonality=True,
        seasonality_mode='multiplicative'
    )

    #history_pd['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(history_pd['ds'], errors = 'coerce', format = '%Y-%m-%d')
    #.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')) 

    # fit the model
    model.fit(history_pd.loc[:,['ds','y']])

    # configure predictions
    future_pd = model.make_future_dataframe(
        periods=20,
        freq='W')

    # make predictions
    results_pd = model.predict(future_pd)

    # return predictions
    return pd.DataFrame({

        'segment':history_pd['segment'].values[0],
        'ds': [results_pd.loc[:,'ds'].values.tolist()],
        'trend': [results_pd.loc[:,'ds'].values.tolist()],
        'trend_upper': [results_pd.loc[:,'trend_upper'].values.tolist()],
        'trend_lower': [results_pd.loc[:,'trend_lower'].values.tolist()],
        'yearly': [results_pd.loc[:,'yearly'].values.tolist()],
        'yearly_upper': [results_pd.loc[:,'yearly_upper'].values.tolist()],
        'yearly_lower': [results_pd.loc[:,'yearly_lower'].values.tolist()],
        'yhat': [results_pd.loc[:,'yhat'].values.tolist()],
        'yhat_upper': [results_pd.loc[:,'yhat_upper'].values.tolist()],
        'yhat_lower': [results_pd.loc[:,'yhat_lower'].values.tolist()],
        'multiplicative_terms': [results_pd.loc[:,'multiplicative_terms'].values.tolist()],
        'multiplicative_terms_upper': [results_pd.loc[:,'multiplicative_terms_upper'].values.tolist()],
        'multiplicative_terms_lower': [results_pd.loc[:,'multiplicative_terms_lower'].values.tolist()],
        'additive_terms': [results_pd.loc[:,'additive_terms'].values.tolist()],
        'additive_terms_upper': [results_pd.loc[:,'additive_terms_upper'].values.tolist()],
        'additive_terms_lower': [results_pd.loc[:,'additive_terms_lower'].values.tolist()]

    })
    #return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(results_pd),pd.DataFrame(history_pd[['segment']].values[0])], axis = 1)




results =df3.groupBy('segment').apply(forecast_loans)


results.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tweaked my code to the following and **downgraded to pyarrow 0.14** as suggested here [Pandas scalar UDF failing, IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458415/pandas-scalar-udf-failing-illegalargumentexception) and it all worked! I believe downgrading pyarrow to 0.14 was the key for spark 2.x versions as commented on stackoverflow.

The comment says the following "The issue is not with pyarrow's new release, it is spark which has to upgrade and become compatible with pyarrow.(i am afraid we have to wait for spark 3.0 to use the latest pyarrow)"

```
%livycd.pyspark

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType,TimestampType,ArrayType,DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from fbprophet import Prophet
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


result_schema = StructType([

    StructField('segment', StringType(), True),
    StructField('ds', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('trend', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('trend_upper', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('trend_lower', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('yearly', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('yearly_upper', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('yearly_lower', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('yhat', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('yhat_upper', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('yhat_lower', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('multiplicative_terms', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('multiplicative_terms_upper', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('multiplicative_terms_lower', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('additive_terms', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('additive_terms_upper', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('additive_terms_lower', DoubleType(), True),

    ])


@pandas_udf(result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def forecast_loans(df):

    def prophet_model(df,test_start_date):

        df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])

        # train
        ts_train = (df
                    .query('ds < @test_start_date')
                    .sort_values('ds')
                    )
        # test
        ts_test = (df
                   .query('ds >= @test_start_date')
                   .sort_values('ds')
                   .drop('y', axis=1)
                   )

        print(ts_test.columns)

        # instantiate the model, configure the parameters
        model = Prophet(
            interval_width=0.95,
            growth='linear',
            daily_seasonality=False,
            weekly_seasonality=False,
            yearly_seasonality=True,
            seasonality_mode='multiplicative'
        )

        # fit the model

        model.fit(ts_train.loc[:,['ds','y']])

        # configure predictions
        future_pd = model.make_future_dataframe(
            periods=len(ts_test),
            freq='W')

        # make predictions
        results_pd = model.predict(future_pd)
        results_pd = pd.concat([results_pd,df['segment']],axis = 1)

        return pd.DataFrame(results_pd, columns = result_schema.fieldNames())

    # return predictions
    return prophet_model(df, test_start_date= '2019-03-31')




results =df3.groupBy('segment').apply(forecast_loans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Spark 2.3.x or 2.4.x and PyArrow >= 0.15.0, there is a known [compatibility issue between PyArrow and Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#compatibiliy-setting-for-pyarrow--0150-and-spark-23x-24x).

The simplest solution is to set the environment variable `ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1`.  The Spark documentation recommends setting it in `conf/spark-env.sh`, but you can set it in your Linux shell, and it is also possible to set it before creating your `spark_session` in your Python script or shell.

```
import os
os.ENVIRON["ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT"] = "1"
spark_session = ...
```

Alternatively, you can downgrade PyArrow if that is an option for you, as noted in the other answer.