# Pyspark, prophet, pandas UDF - [8906 rows x 3 columns] of type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use '

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am stuck and have tried every suggestion for resolving similiar issue.

**I am trying to scale a facebook prophet model using pyspark and PandasUDF** similiar to [Forecasting with facebook prophet using Pandas udf in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509033/forecasting-with-facebook-prophet-using-pandas-udf-in-spark) .
The end result I am getting is pandas dataframe with some error and I cannot see the results. I have tried both pandas and spark dataframes, but it doesn't work.

I guess it is an easy fix, but I have lost days on this already. Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


df = pd.read_excel("All Mylan products value&units 2015-2020.xlsx")

df.drop(['Region', 'Channel', 'Product - Level 0', 'Product - Level 1', 'Time - Level 0', 'Time - Level 1', 'Sales RET [BGN]'],axis=1, inplace =True)

df

df.columns ='prod','ds','y'
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])

df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

df1 = df.groupby(by='prod')

df1.head()

from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# Create a spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
#create schema using sparkDF
schema = StructType([
        StructField("prod", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ds", DateType(), True),
        StructField("y", DoubleType(), True)
    ])

import os
os.environ["ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT"] = "0"
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema)

from fbprophet import Prophet

sparkschema = sparkdf.schema

mySchema = StructType([ StructField("prod", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("ds", DateType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("trend", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("yhat_lower", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("yhat_upper", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("trend_lower", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("trend_upper", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("monthly", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("monthly_lower", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("monthly_upper'", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("multiplicative_terms", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("multiplicative_terms_lower", DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField('multiplicative_terms_upper', DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField('additive_terms', DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField('additive_terms_lower', DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField('additive_terms_upper', DoubleType(), True)\
                       ,StructField('yhat', DoubleType(), True)])

@pandas_udf(sparkschema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def forecast(df):

    model = Prophet(
        growth="linear",
        interval_width=0.10,
        seasonality_mode="multiplicative",
        yearly_seasonality=False,
        weekly_seasonality=False,
        daily_seasonality=False,
    ).add_seasonality(name="monthly", period=12 * 30.5, fourier_order=12)

    model.fit(df.loc[:, ["ds", "y"]])

    futper = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq="M")
    results_pd = model.predict(futper)
    results_pd = pd.concat([results_pd, df["prod"]], axis=1)

    return pd.DataFrame(results_pd, columns=mySchema.fieldNames())

results = sparkdf.groupby('prod').apply(forecast)
results.show()

pdres = results.toPandas()
```

The error I got on the last 2 rows are:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-d072fc517970> in <module>
     20 
     21 results = sparkdf.groupby('prod').apply(forecast)
---> 22 results.show()

C:\SPARK\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    405         """
    406         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 407             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    408         else:
    409             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\SPARK\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     96     def deco(*a, **kw):
     97         try:
---> 98             return f(*a, **kw)
     99         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    100             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1193.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 20.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 75, DESKTOP-LE3RNA6, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PZashev\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-d86ed11f-022a-4dfa-8616-a9b2e2f9784b\01\temp_shuffle_39ce5516-b787-48c4-af99-a2d32b2fb3a3 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1989)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2116)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2137)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3482)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2581)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2581)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2788)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:334)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PZashev\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-d86ed11f-022a-4dfa-8616-a9b2e2f9784b\01\temp_shuffle_39ce5516-b787-48c4-af99-a2d32b2fb3a3 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

and

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-fea8c4aadf2a> in <module>
----> 1 pdres = results.toPandas()

C:\SPARK\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   2224 
   2225         # Below is toPandas without Arrow optimization.
-> 2226         pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
   2227 
   2228         dtype = {}

C:\SPARK\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in collect(self)
    561         """
    562         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 563             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    564         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    565 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\SPARK\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     96     def deco(*a, **kw):
     97         try:
---> 98             return f(*a, **kw)
     99         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    100             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1193.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 22.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 89, DESKTOP-LE3RNA6, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PZashev\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-d86ed11f-022a-4dfa-8616-a9b2e2f9784b\31\temp_shuffle_e9340b3c-7c60-4fd9-b8ae-5eff51d457bd (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1989)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2116)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2137)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2181)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3310)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PZashev\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-d86ed11f-022a-4dfa-8616-a9b2e2f9784b\31\temp_shuffle_e9340b3c-7c60-4fd9-b8ae-5eff51d457bd (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of the grouped map is stored in results, not the UDF itself. Drop your inner UDF function and get your results from `results`:

```py
@pandas_udf(mySchema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def forecast(df):

    model = Prophet(
        growth="linear",
        interval_width=0.10,
        seasonality_mode="multiplicative",
        yearly_seasonality=False,
        weekly_seasonality=False,
        daily_seasonality=False,
    ).add_seasonality(name="monthly", period=12 * 30.5, fourier_order=12)

    model.fit(df.loc[:, ["ds", "y"]])

    futper = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq="M")
    results_pd = model.predict(futper)
    results_pd = pd.concat([results_pd, df["prod"]], axis=1)

    return pd.DataFrame(results_pd, columns=mySchema.fieldNames())

results = sparkdf.groupby('prod').apply(forecast)
results.columns
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your reply. But I still can't see the results using results.show i get an error
```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o656.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 43, DESKTOP-LE3RNA6, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\...```
Can you tell me what to do with this results so that I can see the values, ideally the whole dataframe?

Comment: Please edit the question with the new error at the bottom. Put the full stack trace in, like you did with the original error.

Comment: Ok, this is a different issue, with a number of potential causes. I suggest you open a new question with all the detail (stack trace, cluster size and configuration, etc...), and remove the new stack trace from this question. If your original problem was solved, please accept.

Comment: Similiar solutions I have looked into didn't require any cluster configuration. So I have not done anything. Can you show me some material so I can get an idea what needs to be added.